# Modifiying shell script so that it does not run if serial number and part number are not given

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script which runs even when I don't give serial number and part number. I want to make it stop if any one of them or both are missing.

```
usage () {
    echo -e "Usage: sudo bash step1.sh -s serial_number -m prod_model_number"
}

serial_number=123456789012343C
prod_model="#######"

while getopts s:m: opt
do
    case $opt in 
    s)   serial_number="$OPTARG"
         ;;
    m)   prod_model="$OPTARG"
         ;;
    '?') usage
         exit 1
         ;;
    esac
done

echo -e "Serial number ($serial_number)"
echo -e "Product model ($prod_model)"

# Silently remove log file
if [ -e $LOCAL_STEP_ONE_LOGFILE ]
then
    rm -f $LOCAL_STEP_ONE_LOGFILE
fi

echo -e "Serial number ($serial_number)" >> $LOCAL_STEP_ONE_LOGFILE
echo -e "Product model ($prod_model)" >> $LOCAL_STEP_ONE_LOGFILE

/bin/bash ./0_get_EK_pub.sh >> $LOCAL_STEP_ONE_LOGFILE
/bin/bash ./1_generate_IAK.sh >> $LOCAL_STEP_ONE_LOGFILE
/bin/bash ./2_generate_IDevID.sh >> $LOCAL_STEP_ONE_LOGFILE
/bin/bash ./3_certify_IDevID_with_IAK.sh >> $LOCAL_STEP_ONE_LOGFILE
/bin/bash ./4_build_csr_idevid.sh -s "$serial_number" -m "$prod_model" >> $LOCAL_STEP_ONE_LOGFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your script gives serial_number and prod_model default values when no arguments provided.

```
serial_number=123456789012343C
prod_model="#######"
```

You need to remove them then check if serial_number or prod_model is empty to determine if serial_number and prod_model are given